# Selenium how to locate cell in a table by value (python)

Tags: selenium

The table is dynamically generated and cells looks like

```
<div class="tableRow">
  <input name="fileExt" type="hidden" value="complete">
  <div class="tableCell rbpCheckBox">
    <input data-index="0" name="SelectItem" type="checkbox" class="check" value="150909_ACTG_01_scyther_WD14R05C12.150910010134">
    <input name="SelectPFolderName" type="hidden" value="P_0_2015-09-10-010132_master_ac-analysis_v2.3.0">
  </div>
  <div class="tableCell accordion-toggle cursor-pointer" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collaspseDiv_150909_ACTG_01_scyther_WD14R05C12_150910010134">
    <p class="ellipsis rbpName" title="150909_ACTG_01_scyther_WD14R05C12">
      150909_ACTG_01_scyther_WD14R05C12
    </p>
    <input type="hidden" name="formatted_run_name" id="150909_ACTG_01_scyther_WD14R05C12.150910010134"
    value="150909_ACTG_01_scyther_WD14R05C12">
  </div>
  <div class="tableCell">
    <span class="rbpStatus rbpStatusPadding" title="multichunk analysis pending at master">
      <img src=" done.png " title="Done" class="runStatusImgTag">
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="tableCell">
    <p class="rbpStatus">
      scyther
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="tableCell">
    <p class="rbpStatus">
      2015-09-10 01:01:35
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The reason why I have to locate the cell by value is because I would like to use it as confirmation that element is present on the page and we are ready to next step\action in the test-case, so I have to wait until some element will be displayed on the page and decided to wait for this cell

```
<div class="tableCell">
  <p class="rbpStatus">
    scyther
  </p>
</div>
```

I'm trying to use something like

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "p.rbpStatus[contains('scyther')]")))
```

Comment: Your html for generated table looks invalid at https://validator.w3.org.

Comment: Provided part of html is just a sample of code, actual table is very big and can not be used as example, so I removed unnecessary part... I guess that part that I removed after the discussed cell - the reason of invalid validation, but it is should not be a problem, thank you for notice.

Answer (score 0):

**css selectors** do not support `contains` function.

To wait for -

```
<div class="tableCell">
  <p class="rbpStatus">
    scyther
  </p>
</div>
```

Try this:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//p[contains(@class,'rbpStatus') and contains(text(),'scyther')]")))
```

Comment: `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//p[@class='rbpStatus']")))` **found some element**, but `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//p[@class='rbpStatus' and contains('scyther')]")))` **is timing out**

Comment: How much is your internet connection speed? have you tried with different wait value not just 10 ?

Comment: Have a try WebDriverWait(driver,10000).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//p[contains(@class,'rbpStatus')]")))

Comment: `WebDriverWait(driver,10000).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//p[contains(@class,'rbpStatus')]")))` - works very fast... less than a second